# Shading a dependency in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have two dependencies imported via Maven that both import a common library, but at different versions but the versions are not compatible with each other. Essentially the problem described [in this post](https://www.ricston.com/blog/solving-dependency-conflicts-maven/):

[image: dependency tree]

But unfortunately for me, the solution is not as simple as the blog post describes, because there isn't a common version of package `Z` that works for both dependencies.

Skipping the poor design decisions that led to this point as I don't control any of these libraries, I'm looking to repackage one of the top-level dependencies and shade all of its dependencies so it can essentially use its own, isolated version of `Z`. Is this possible to accomplish with Maven?

One solution I have considered is isolating all the classes that depend on package `Y` and putting them in a separate application and shipping that as a shaded `jar` which `X` imports, however I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to accomplish that.

Comment: Have you looked into using Java 9's module system to solve this problem?

Comment: @Gimby Unfortunately, one of the dependencies doesn't support Java 9 yet (as in it doesn't compile) so I don't think that will be an option for me, but I appreciate the pointer, I didn't know about it until now.

Comment: The pre-java 9 solution would be to apply OSGI, but to modulerize an existing application may be a bit of a leap to begin with. In any case I don't really get your question... you already tagged this with the maven-shade-plugin, one possible solution. So... use it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious in the documentation, but how? Everything I've seen on maven-shade-plugin seems to suggest it only allows you to shade the project you're working on, not shade an immediate dependency and its dependencies. I added the tag on the chance that it can do that and somebody knew how, but I guess I do not myself. :(

Comment: It's a combination of making a fat-jar and shading; fat jarring means packing all the dependency jars into one large jar which you can then distribute. So in your case you could fat-jar module Y and then the old version of Z is packaged into it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As everyone has suggested you can use the **maven-shade-plugin**. Open source projects handle this by creating one maven sub project for each dependency that needs to be shaded. So in your case you would need 3 maven projects:

1. One for shading dependency Y
2. One for shading dependency G
3. One for your original project. Your original project includes the artifacts created in 1. and 2. as dependencies.

Your maven project hierarchy would look like this:

- project

  - pom.xml
  - shade-Y

    - pom.xml
  - shade-G

    - pom.xml
  - application

    - pom.xml

An example of a project which has a maven sub project for shading a dependency is [here](https://github.com/apache/apex-core). Look at the **shaded-ning19** folder to see how to create a dedicated maven project for shading a dependency.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the example project, that's extremely helpful!

Comment: Example with poms would be nice