# same accessible package from two different modules in Lucene leading Eclipse to raise an error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lucene

I installed Lucene v8.11.1 and tried to run it on Eclipse.
I followed all the instructions from the original resource: [LuceneTutorial.com](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html). I installed the jar files, required to function Lucene, into my project as external libraries. Finally I took the example from the website to use it, but it gives me this error when I import the `StandardAnalyzer` class: "**The package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard is accessible from more than one module: lucene.analyzers.common, lucene.core**"

[image: Lucene program in Eclipse Shows an error of one package is accessible from two different modules]

Apparently, Eclipse cannot tell from which module I am importing this class.

I looked for a solution to this issue, but could not found I any solution that fit my problem. Same problem other people have mentioned but none of which solve my problem:

a. [a question on StackOVerFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607637/lucene-split-package-module-reads-package-org-apache-lucene-analysis-standard)

b. [MarkLogic website](https://markmail.org/message/askcvrkxchi2nbl3?q=list:org%2Eapache%2Elucene%2Esolr-dev)

c. [Other question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607637/lucene-split-package-module-reads-package-org-apache-lucene-analysis-standard)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message `The package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard is accessible from more than one module: lucene.analyzers.common, lucene.core` means you have the modules `lucene.analyzers.common` and `lucene.core` on the modulepath (_Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Libraries_) which both contains the package `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard` and this is illegal in Java 9 or higher. Delete your `module-info.java` file and move the libraries from the modulepath to the classpath.

Comment: @howlger That solved the problem. Thanks a lot. One of the posts for the same problem has suggested to Delete the module file. I did that, but the error is still there. You gave more details about it.. Thanks again.

Comment: For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250